# Flutter Connection Failed (SocketException: Network is unreachable, errno = 51)

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have encountered an issue with the mobile internet connection in my Flutter app. This problem occurs on both Android and iOS. When I attempt to make a request to my server, everything works perfectly fine when using Wi-Fi. However, on some devices, when using a mobile network, the request fails. I have tried using a different random API, and it works, but with my development server, it gives an error. I have also tried switching from 'http' to 'https' and changing the default port from 8000 to others, but none of these changes helped. Oddly, I found that resetting all my network settings on my iPhone temporarily resolved the issue, but later in the day, the same error occurred again. Thank you for your help!
[SocketException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp3Zr.png)

I tried to request my server with post and get requests. I used 'http' and 'dio' libraries. But i have this error Connection Failed (SocketException: Network is unreachable, errno = 51) on some devices when i am using mobile network.
Also i added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to my AndroidManifest, of course.

Comment: Seems like a server side issue.

Comment: I talked with devops and backender and they dont what exactly a problem. So my options are limited...